# Finding inequality with complex numbers and constants

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, inequality, partial-differential-equations

Consider $I=\{1,\ldots, m\}$, $J=\{m+1,\ldots, d\}$ with $d-m=n$ and $u\in\mathbb{C}^d$. Moreover, let $\alpha_i$ be some symmetric, positive semi-definite $d\times d$-matrix and $\beta_i$ some $d$-vector for $i\in I$. I'm trying to prove following inequality: For $i\in I$, it holds:

$$
\begin{align}
&\quad\frac{1}{2}(\alpha_i)_{ii}\overline{u_i}u_i\Re(u_i)+\Re(\overline{u_i}u_i(\alpha_{i})_{iJ}u_J)+\frac{1}{2}\Re(\overline{u_i}u_J^\top (\alpha_{i})_{JJ}u_J)+\Re(\overline{u_i}\beta_i^\top u)\\
&\le\frac{K}{2}(1+\lVert (\Re(u_I)^+\rVert+\lVert u_J\rVert^2)(1+\lVert u_I \rVert^2)
\end{align}
$$

Let $K$ just be an upper bound for all absolute values of the entries in $\alpha_i$ or $\beta_i$. Then I would find

$$
\begin{align}
&\quad\frac{1}{2}(\alpha_i)_{ii}\overline{u_i}u_i\Re(u_i)+\Re(\overline{u_i}u_i(\alpha_{i})_{iJ}u_J)+\frac{1}{2}\Re(\overline{u_i}u_J^\top (\alpha_{i})_{JJ}u_J)+\Re(\overline{u_i}\beta_i^\top u)\\
&\le\frac{K}{2}\Big(\overline{u_i}u_i\Re(u_i)+\overline{u_i}u_i\sum_{j\in J}\Re(u_j)+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j,k\in J}\Re(\overline{u_i}u_j u_k)+\sum_{k=1}^d\Re(\overline{u_i} u_k)\Big)
\end{align}
$$

However, I am not able to find an proper estimation for the next steps. How could I go on from here?

I'd be  thankful for any hint or help. Thank you in advance!